# Sign in functionality not working in particular pages of site

Tags: php, authentication

In my site, the sign in functionality works fine when we login from index page. But it is not logged in when we login from other pages except index page in my site.

**http://domain.com/mysite/index.php**

When login from this page, The functionality works fine and after login it shows the page as shown below

[image: After successful login]

If we login from other pages in my site it does not work fine and it shows the page as
**http://mysite.com/samplefolder/detailpage.php?pollid=2&chid=2**

[image: After login also it shows sign in]

**Signin.php**

```
<?php
include("jalert.php");
if (array_key_exists("login", $_GET)) {
```

$oauth_provider = $_GET['oauth_provider'];
if ($oauth_provider == 'twitter') {
header("Location: login-twitter.php");
}
}
?>

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#new_user_session_ajax").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
       var email = $('#userid').val();
       var password = $('#signin_password').val();
       var remember = $('#user_session_remember_me').val();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxlogin.php",
        data: "userid="+email+"&password1="+password+"&rememberme="+remember+""
        }).done(function( msg )  {
    if(msg)
    {
        $('#error').html(msg);
    }
    else
    {
        window.location.href="index.php";
    }

});
});
});

</script>


<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" name="login" onsubmit="return checkreg();" class="no_scroll_animation validate no_bump ajax" id="new_user_session_ajax" method="post">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="">
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="yRcKhChgROcxunh7A7zRQVroShpYbO6e6PaAO4JHUtg=">
</div>

<input id="after_url" name="redirect_after_login" type="hidden" value="/">


<li class="remember_me clear">
<input name="user_session[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input checked="checked" id="external_remember_me_popup" name="remember_me" type="checkbox" value="1">
<label for="external_remember_me_popup">Remember me</label>


<h5>Sign in with email</h5>


<li><input autocapitalize="off" class="validate validate_required validate_email placeholder" id="userid" name="userid" value="Email Address"
           onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email Address') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value ='Email Address'}"  title="email" type="email" value=""></li>

<li><input autocapitalize="off" class="validate validate_required placeholder" id="signin_password" name="password1" value="Password"
           onfocus="if(this.value == 'Password') {this.value='';this.type='password'}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value ='Password';this.type ='text'}" type="text" validate:message="Please enter your password" value=""></li><li class="last">


    <input class="button" name="login" type="submit" value="Login"  >
<div class="keepmeloggedin"><input name="rememberme" type="hidden" value="remember me"><input checked="checked" id="user_session_remember_me" value="remember me" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" value="1">&nbsp; Remember me</div><div class="forgotPassword">
<a class="forget_pass" href="forgot_password.php" id="forgotPasswordLink" rel="nofollow">Forgot password?</a></div></li></ul></div></form>
```

**Ajaxlogin.php**

```
<?php 
include("classes.php");
$jeob = new EF_Sql();

    $email= $_POST['userid'];

    $password= $_POST['password1'];

    $papas=base64_encode($password);

    $check = $_POST['rememberme'];



        $tablename="user_record";

    $select_qry = $jeob->SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ".$jeob->dbprefix.$tablename." WHERE email ='$email' AND password ='$papas' AND active_link='1' ");

$kiss="SELECT * FROM ".$jeob->dbprefix.$tablename." WHERE email ='$email' AND password ='$papas'";

        if($jeob->SqlRows($select_qry) == "0"){                 

         echo "Invalid Username and Password";


        } else {


        if($check) {

                setcookie("username", $email, time() + 3600);       // Sets the cookie username

        }

        $getuser = $jeob->SqlFetch($select_qry);

        $_SESSION['userid'] = $getuser['user_id'];  

        $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = "normal";

        $_SESSION['email'] = $getuser['email'];     

        }
?>
```

Comment: can you please post code for display of sign in text or image?

Comment: The login coding was posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are calling `session_start();` at the top of each file. It is likely you are missing that on some pages so the session does not carry over and as such it appears as if the user is logged out.

Comment: Yes, already the page contains the session_start(); at the top of the file

Comment: @Rithu, post the code that is used to create the Sign In link, and also any relevent authentication code.

Comment: The sign in coding was posted